# ssh: connect to host xxx.y.z.aaa port 22: Connection refused

Tags: git, ssh

I am very new to git.  Trying to setup my own bare git remote repository in my Linux server and push files from my local repository.  I gone through some manuals and setup the remote and local repoistories.

When I do push from my local repository I am getting connection refused.  I already created a SSH key in server and I am able to connect via Putty from my local terminal using a different port (34891).

Need some help how can I push my local repository to my remote repository.

Below is from my server.  The remote repository looks ok

```
[myname@octopus gitrepo.git]$ pwd
/media2/myname/gitrepo.git
[myname@octopus gitrepo.git]$ ls -l
total 28
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname myname   23 Oct 17 23:45 HEAD
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname myname   84 Oct 17 23:45 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myname myname   73 Oct 17 23:45 description
drwxrwxr-x 2 myname myname 4096 Oct 17 23:45 hooks
drwxrwxr-x 2 myname myname 4096 Oct 17 23:45 info
drwxrwxr-x 4 myname myname 4096 Oct 17 23:45 objects
drwxrwxr-x 4 myname myname 4096 Oct 17 23:45 refs
[myname@octopus gitrepo.git]$
```

Below are the commands used in my local repository

```
Malai@MALAI MINGW64 /e/gitrepo/test (master)
$ ls
new.txt

Malai@MALAI MINGW64 /e/gitrepo/test (master)
$ git remote add origin myname@xxx.y.z.aaa:/media2/myname/gitrepo.git

Malai@MALAI MINGW64 /e/gitrepo/test (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  myname@xxx.y.z.aaa:/media2/myname/gitrepo.git (fetch)
origin  myname@xxx.y.z.aaa:/media2/myname/gitrepo.git (push)

Malai@MALAI MINGW64 /e/gitrepo/test (master)
$ git push -u origin master
ssh: connect to host xxx.y.z.aaa port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also tried adding the port number as below and still the same error

```
git remote add origin myname@xxx.y.z.aaa:34891/media2/myname/gitrepo.git
```

In ssh_config I added the IP address and port number as below

```
Host xxx.y.z.aaa
Port 34891
```

When I try to connect, it asked for a password.  But is says permission denied.

```
Malai@MALAI MINGW64 /e/gitrepo/test (master)
$ ssh -T -p 34891 myname@xxx.y.z.aaa
myname@xxx.y.z.aaa's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Am I missing something? Should i put the private key some where? or any config should i do in ssh config?

Comment: You need to tell Git about that port: `git remote add origin myname@xxx.y.z.aaa:34891/media2/myname/gitrepo.git`

Comment: @Biffen no it doesn't work with same error.  Updated my question also.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved after making the below changes.

Edited the ssh_config file under C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh and added the below lines

```
Host xxx.y.z.aaa
Port 34891
IdentityFile E:\sshkeys\ssh_myname
```

IdentifyFile is the path of the id_rsa file downloaded from my server.

Once make these changes and it started working

```
Malai@MALAI MINGW64 /e/gitrepo/test (master)
$ git push -u origin master
Enter passphrase for key 'E:\sshkeys\ssh_myname':
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 211 bytes | 70.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To xxx.y.z.aaa:/media2/myname/gitrepo.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Linux cluster, which was solved by adding:

```
[user]
email = name@address.com
```

to

```
.../repository/.git/config
```